# What is it called when a person is used to hide an action or another person?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

What is it called when you use one person to hide the real person or action ? What is that person called.?

Example: someone being investigated for cheating. He doesn't want the real woman (who he's cheating with) to be discovered by his wife. So, he goes out with his friend (another woman) often and in public... To prove to his wife that it's just "a friendship"...     And that way, his wife won't look further into the real woman her husband is cheating with.

So the question is:
What is the friend being used as?
Or
What would the noun be for the friend?
What is she? In this case (the friend... Not the cheater woman)

Comment: Decoy, scapegoat, beard? Please provide some context.

Comment: I think we're going to need **far** more information about what are describing here. *Proxy* might fit, *decoy* might fit... There's helpful advice in the [single-word-request tag info](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info).

Comment: You need to give more details of your intended context. For example, there are words/concepts such as ***mule, scapegoat*** and ***stalking horse***, all of which are very different.

Comment: @AndrewLeach , I wrote an example above. Hopefully it makes sense

Comment: The person is a decoy, The activity is misdirection.

Comment: In some cases the 'other woman's may also be/provide an **alabi**.

Comment: @SteveLovell; so the friend would be the alibi? Or the 'mistress'?

Comment: If the man says he is with the friend when he is with his mistress, he uses the friend as "an alabi". Usually an alabi is something like an explanation that you couldn't have committed a crime because someone else can vouch for your whereabouts at the time of the crime. This is similar, but we are probably not imagining that the friend actually be asked only that the man offering her name is a plausible of where he was.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The person is being used as a **[decoy](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/decoy)**:

> 1.1 A person or thing used to mislead or lure someone into a trap.
>
> *‘we need a decoy to distract their attention’*

The activity described is **[misdirection](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/misdirection)**:

> 1 *[mass noun]* The action or process of directing someone to the wrong place or in the wrong direction.
>
> *‘the deliberate misdirection that had put me off the track’*

Answer (score 2):

> **Red herring**
> /noun
>
> 2. something intended to divert attention from the real problem or matter at hand; a misleading clue.
>
> [Source: Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/red-herring)

Answer (score 1):

> **Smoke screen**
> /noun
>
> 2. Something intended to disguise, conceal, or deceive; camouflage.
>
> [Source: Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/smoke--screen)